# Failed to connect to any peer event hubs. It is required that at least 1 event hub has been connected to receive the commit event

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

Have created new folder and followed the steps given in 
https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/developer-tutorial
and currently am stuck at  below command 
composer network start --networkName tutorial-network --networkVersion 0.0.1 --networkAdmin admin --networkAdminEnrollSecret adminpw --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --file networkadmin.card

getting below error while running it.

D:\HF\tutorial-network>composer network start --networkName tutorial-network --networkVersion 0.0.1 --networkAdmin admin --networkAdminEnrollSecret adminpw --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --file networkadmin.card
Starting business network tutorial-network at version 0.0.1

Processing these Network Admins:
        userName: admin

× Starting business network definition. This may take a minute...
Error: Error trying to start business network. Error: Failed to connect to any peer event hubs. It is required that at least 1 event hub has been connected to receive the commit event
Command failed

Comment: Check the container logs for any errors, also check whether the versions of composer and fabric you're using are compatible.

Comment: I am also facing the same problem does anyone have any solution for this. I am currently using fabric 1.2 and composer version 0.20.5

Answer (score 1):

Please check your connection profile(json) .
Check your peer, orderer, ca and channel configuration according to the architechture
Also ensure that the channel name is correct

I had configured the wrong channel name which was resulting in this error.

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing everything with the supplied scripts

```
byfn.sh -m down
stopFabric.sh
teardownFabric.sh
teardownAllDocker.sh
```

The error happened for me because I was not running the end to end tests when executing

```
./byfn.sh -m up -s couchdb -a
```